# What does the output of ls -l mean?

Tags: linux

I'm wondering, what this particular entry of the output of `ls -l` means. Could someone please explain the meaning of the fields?

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 920788 Mar 28 2013 bash
```

Comment: I think the fact that this question gets asked so many times is proof of poor documentation. The manpage says nothing on the topic

Answer (score 7):

The first block (`-rwxr-xr-x`) means that

- the first character signifies the type of file. '-' for file and 'd' for directory 'l' for a link.
- It is readable, writeable and executable by the user (the first triple `rwx`)
- It is readable and executable by the group (the second triple `r-x`)
- It is readable and executable by anyone (the third triple `r-x`)

The `1` represents number of links (names) for this file.

The next is that the file is owned by the user `root` (the first `root`) and the group `root` (the second `root`).

Then the file size is printed (`920788` bytes in this case).

Then the creation date of the file (in this case `Mar 28 2013`) is printed. This could also be formatted like `Mar 28 08:15` if the year is the current year.

Finally the name of the file (`bash` in this case) is printed.